# Prolog giving instantiation error

Tags: prolog

I am stuck up for a very long time with the prolog error in my homework.

I try to make a addition using `is/2` and it always results in:

```
++Error[XSB/Runtime/P]: [Instantiation] ++Error[XSB]: [Runtime/C] Uninstantiated
 argument of evaluable function +/2
   Goal: _Var + 2, probably as 2nd arg of is/2
```

Any pointer will greatly help me in completing my homework.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when Prolog tries to calculate the value of Cost2, the value of F is still unknown and therefore an addition attempt leads to an instantiation error. You should ensure that F is a ground value when addition is reached.

Comment: But, When I try to assign F value directly to the function call instead of Cost2 is F+Cost1 , it picks up the F value correctly

Comment: As I've explained if the value of F is known, the addition works fine. It reports an error only if the value of F is unknown.